# Edit page for user in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Does anyone here knows how to make an edit page for user? There, they can view their expenses their entered sort by month. I am working on Asp.net and c# language. I  have table in my db that store username, expenses, prices,and month. When user login, they can view only their expenses. I just dont know how to create it since i tried use gridview but it didnt work for me. Thank you :)

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings     ["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ExpTab] WHERE UserID = @username", conn);
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name));

        }
    }
```

ok, here is how i pull current login user data from db. How to show the retrieved data in textbox?

Comment: Can you post your code that you tried? How are we meant to help you if we don't know what the problem is. The GridView sounds like the right control for the task you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. You can get the user's information from the database. You have to code this on your own. Get the UserID of the user once he/she logs and and go to the database to pull their info for that userID and display.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to show the data in a textbox by login.....

save the user name in session from the login page
         Session["UserName"] =UserName;

call this method in your page load method of the page where u want display the user profile

```
        void showuser()
    {
        string Employeename = (string)(Session["UserName"]);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand mycomm=new SqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM [ExpTab] WHERE UserID = @username",con);
        mycomm.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        mycomm.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ;
        SqlDataAdapter showdata = new SqlDataAdapter(mycomm);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        showdata.Fill(ds);
        txtEmployeename.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Emp_Username"].ToString();
        txtBranchName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Branch_BranchName"].ToString();
        txtApprvdby.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Approval_ApprovedBY"].ToString();
        binddropdownlist();
        con.Close();           
    }
```

This should work..if u have any doubts ask me...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you use the gridview, select the data source from your connection, use the session in your login page, and call back in the edit page. In data source setting, use source = session to call it back. Hope this give you the idea of ur question. :)